# How to pass sx prop to Icons with menu.map function in material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, icons

I'm trying to map out a menu with icons in Material UI

its working, but I do not understand how to pass the sx prop into the Icon when using the map function.

this is an example

```
export const Menuitems = [
    {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      to: '/',
      text: 'dashboard',
      icon: (<DashboardIcon />),
    },
    {
      name: 'Pretest',
      to: '/pretest',
      text: 'pretest',
      icon: (<AccessibilityIcon />),
    }, 
  ]

export const ShowMainMenu = (props) => {
  return (
    <Grid item >
    <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} to={props.to}>
    <Paper elevation={6}>
        {props.icon}
        <Typography fontSize={20} fontWeight={600}>{props.name}</Typography>
    </Paper>
    </Link> 
    </Grid>
```

---

in another component, I map over the Menuitems with spread like this:

```
 <Grid container >
  { Menuitems.map((item) => {
       return  <ShowMainMenu {...item} />
    })
  } 
 </Grid>
```

This works fine, but I need to change the size of the Icons with a sx prop.

I would like to have it like this:

```
<DashboardIcon sx={{color: '#002884' , fontSize: 80 }}/>
```

I would prefer not to put styling into the menu-array because I use it in many different settings, so I would like to keep it clean.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to use the sx prop in this context?

Comment: As a heads up, I would figure out a way to make the MainMenu component reusable, rather than reusing the list of menu items in "many different settings". This will take away the complexity if you need to change the menu in the future. i.e. don't export the list every time, but embed the list in a component and use that component everywhere you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining icons as jsx, you can define icons as component references like this:

```
export const Menuitems = [
  {
    name: "Dashboard",
    to: "/",
    text: "dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon
  },
  {
    name: "Pretest",
    to: "/pretest",
    text: "pretest",
    icon: AccessibilityIcon
  }
];
```

And then render the icons inside of `ShowMainMenu` component like this:

```
export const ShowMainMenu = (props) => {
  const IconComponent = props.icon;
  return (
    <Grid item>
      <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} to={props.to}>
        <Paper elevation={6}>
          <IconComponent sx={props.iconSx} />
          <Typography fontSize={20} fontWeight={600}>
            {props.name}
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Link>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

And pass `sx` reference in your `map` function like this:

```
<Grid container>
    {Menuitems.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <ShowMainMenu
          {...item}
          iconSx={{ color: "#002884", fontSize: 80 }}
        />
      );
    })}
</Grid>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-icon-sx-4t64gp?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of this approach.

Comment: This is the solution I would propose for this given problem, however, I wouldn't tie the naming of the props to the library you're using incase you want to switch it out later on. Name it something agnostic like iconStyle.

Comment: Thx, both of you, didn’t think of doing it like that. @BradleyIW I’m new to React so I’m interested in understanding. I’m  slicing the array in some pages due to different layouts, and using the array in both sidebars, breadcrumbs and other submenus. Some pages uses  ie. just 3 elements out of the array, so if I understand you, you suggest to make a reusable/ more generic component , and then manipulate the layout with props like the example above? ( like making props out of Grid and Paper for example ?)

Comment: I would then suggest having smaller components that are styled/named in a way you need i.e. DashboardMenuItem and then import them into a larger component i.e. MainMenu, MainSideBar instead of depending on one list in many places, it'll save you the complexity and keep the components consistent across the different larger components. At least then you can pick and choose which components live in which menu rather than slicing and manipulating a list.